# Why do I keep getting Null

Tags: .net, arraylist, nullreferenceexception

I have an asp.net 2010 app. When I attempt to fill the following class, I keep getting NullReferenceException and I can't figure out why. I instantiate the ArrayLists in New().

```
<Serializable()> _
Public Class Yaya
    Public Sub New()
        _People = New ArrayList
        _PhysicalHouseholds = New ArrayList
        _TaxReturns = New ArrayList
    End Sub

    Public Property People() As ArrayList
    Public Property PhysicalHouseholds() As ArrayList
    Public Property TaxReturns() As ArrayList
End Class
```

Here is the code to populate this class that fails....

```
    Dim oYaya As New Yaya
    Dim oPerson As New Applicant

    oPerson.isApplicant = "Y"
    oPerson.disabled = "N"
    oPerson.student = "N"
    oPerson.eligible = "N"
    oPerson.incarcerated = "N"
    oPerson.livesInState = "Y"

 oYaya.People.Add(oPerson)
```

The MyClass is there...the Person is there. But the People ArrayList within MyClass is nothing even though I instantiate it when the class is MyClass object is created.

Comment: I don't think the backing field for `People` is `_People` Can't you assign the Arraylist directly to `People`?

Comment: `MyClass` is a keyword, so this code isn't even valid. Please show a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @rene *When you declare an auto-implemented property, Visual Basic automatically creates a hidden private field called the backing field to contain the property value. The backing field name is the auto-implemented property name preceded by an underscore (_). For example, if you declare an auto-implemented property named ID, the backing field is named _ID. If you include a member of your class that is also named _ID, you produce a naming conflict and Visual Basic reports a compiler error.* [source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589.aspx)

Comment: @DominicKexel well that shows why I have not much rep in the vb.net tag...